# How to create a reusable button component in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am wondering about best practices when creating a reusable button component in SwiftUI. i.e., a button that I can reuse many places in my project and takes in various parameters and callback functions to perform actions.

I have tried searching online and on forums but I have not found any best practices.

Comment: Whatever you come up with, make sure it works sensibly when Settings > Accessibility > Display & Text Size > Button Shapes is turned on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably all depends how the button should look. On this point alone you could refer to [Apple's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/menus-and-actions/buttons). You should also be aware that buttons may take on a different appearance when Settings > Accessibility > Display & Text Size > Button Shapes is turned on.

Here are some suggested implementation techniques. You will notice from the snippets that I generally use a struct called `Styles` to hold static functions and constants related to styling. This keeps the styling in one place.

1. **A simple call-to-action label, or tappable content with no particular shape.** When Button Shapes is turned on, the button should take on an enclosing gray background.

-> Just use a regular `Button`, for example:

```swift
Button(
    LocalizedStringKey(cancelKey),
    role: .cancel,
    action: doCancel
)
```

2. **A button with a traditional shape**, such as a `RoundedRectangle` or `Capsule`. Since it already looks like a button, the appearance does not need to change when Button Shapes is turned on.

-> Use a `Button` and apply a `.buttonStyle`, for example:

```swift
/// A ButtonStyle for a regular rectangular button with rounded corners.
/// By using a ButtonStyle, the buttons don't change shape when the device
/// setting Button Spapes is turned on. In particular, they don't get bloated
/// with a transparent grey surround
struct RegularButton: ButtonStyle {
    private let bgColor: Color
    private let cornerRadius: CGFloat

    init(
        bgColor: Color,
        cornerRadius: CGFloat = Styles.cornerRadius
    ) {
        self.bgColor = bgColor
        self.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    }
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .background(bgColor)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius))
    }
}

/// Factory method for a regular button
static func createRegularButton(
    label: String,
    action: @escaping () -> Void
) -> some View {
    Button(action: action) {
        Text(LocalizedStringKey(label))
        .foregroundColor(Styles.myRegularButtonLabelColor)
        .padding()
    }
    .buttonStyle(
        RegularButton(bgColor: Styles.myRegularButtonBgColor)
    )
}
```

3. **Tappable content with a well-defined shape and embedded label.** No highlighting needed when button shapes is turned on.

-> Just apply an `.onTapGesture` to the content. If the area includes empty space then it can help to apply a `.contentShape`, so that the empty space is tappable too:

```swift
MyContent()

    // Setting contentShape increases the area which
    // is sensitive to tap
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    .onTapGesture(perform: action)
```

4. **A button represented by a symbol.** No highlighting needed when Button Shapes is turned on.

-> This is actually another case of type 3. Just apply `.onTapGesture` to an `Image`. Apple recommends 44x44 as the minimum size for a tappable area in the guidelines mentioned above. It is good practice to provide an accessibility label too:

```swift
Image(systemName: theIconName)
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFit()
    .padding(10)
    .foregroundColor(Styles.mySymbolButtonFg)
    .frame(width: 44, height: 44)

    // Setting the content shape allows taps to work anywhere
    // within the frame, including transparent parts
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    .accessibilityLabel(Text(LocalizedStringKey(altTextLabel)))
    .onTapGesture(perform: action)
```

5. **Simple tappable text that behaves like an HTML link.** When Button Shapes is turned on, the text should be underlined.

-> Use `Text` with `.onTapGesture` and conditional underlining:

```swift
static func textLink(_ label: String, buttonShapesEnabled: Bool) -> Text {
    let text = Text(LocalizedStringKey(label))
    return buttonShapesEnabled
        ? text.underline()
        : text
}

/// The environment value that indicates whether the setting Button Shapes is enabled
@Environment(\.accessibilityShowButtonShapes) private var accessibilityShowButtonShapes: Bool

Styles.textLink(
    helpKey,
    buttonShapesEnabled: accessibilityShowButtonShapes
)
.foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.link))
.onTapGesture(perform: action)
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a best practice in-terms of an industry standard for buttons, but creating a re-usuable component will go a long way in keeping all UI consistent in the app.

```
struct CustomButton: View {
  var text: String                     // text to render inside the button
  var submissionHandler: () -> Void   // function that gets called on submission

  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      handler()
    }, label: {
      Text(text)
    })
      .accessibility(value: Text("\(text) Button")).   // make sure to include accessibility labels
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var body: some View {
  Text("Rendering Button")
  CustomButton(text: "hello", submissionHandler: {
    print("Handling button submission")
  }

}
```

You can go a step further and add styling options to this button component that gets conditionally selected based on parameters passed.

Hope this helps!