# Is there other alternative other than extending Button for ButtonStyle?

Tags: swift, swiftui

My goal is to have conditional button style. However, `.buttonStyle(selected : .bordered : .borderedProminent)` can't be used.

```
struct DepartureArrivalView: View {
    @Binding var value: String
    @Binding var selected: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                Text(value)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .font(.title)
            }
            .customButtonStyle(selected)
            .padding(16)
        }
    }
}
extension Button {
    @ViewBuilder
    func customButtonStyle(_ selected: Bool) -> some View {
        switch selected {
        case true:
            self.buttonStyle(.bordered)
        case false:
            self.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct DepartureArrivalView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DepartureArrivalView(value: .constant("A"), selected: .constant(true))
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Why can you not use the syntax in your question? Also, you can make your own button style that can set everything based on conditions easily. That might be a better way to go.

Comment: I prefer to avoid adding new method to existing library.

Comment: Buttons do not have to be implemented using ```Button```. You might find [How to create a reusable button component in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76105625) useful.

Comment: @JasonRichDarmawan it’s not a new function. The ButtonStyle would be a new type. Just like `DepartureArrivalView` is a new type. SwiftUI and the way it is set up is there for you to extend with your own types and components etc…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `.bordered` and `.borderedProminent` don't conform to [`ButtonStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/buttonstyle#). They conform to [`PrimitiveButtonStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/primitivebuttonstyle#).

So, one way to solve this is by introducing a `PrimitiveButtonStyle` that wraps the two styles you want to choose from. To do it in a generic, reusable way, make it generic over the two styles:

```
enum Either<Left, Right> {
    case left(Left)
    case right(Right)
}

extension Either: PrimitiveButtonStyle where Left: PrimitiveButtonStyle, Right: PrimitiveButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        switch self {
        case .left(let left):
            left.makeBody(configuration: configuration)
        case .right(let right):
            right.makeBody(configuration: configuration)
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
struct DepartureArrivalView: View {
    @Binding var value: String
    @Binding var selected: Bool

    private var style: some PrimitiveButtonStyle {
        return selected ? Either.left(.bordered) : .right(.borderedProminent)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                Text(value)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .font(.title)
            }
            .buttonStyle(style)
            .padding(16)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really good. I struggled for a while trying to come up with something that didn't break identity. Very useful technique.