# How can I remove Button opacity animation on tap?

Tags: ios, user-interface, button, swiftui, mobile-development

I hava a custom dropdown list and the top item is a button (because .onTapGesture didn't work with the items I have in the title) for which I want to remove the tap effect (oppacity change of the text). When I tap on selected Item I would like to be the same as a simple Text, no tap effect.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgBu1.gif)

I tried .animation(nil) and .buttonStyle(.plain) but with no luck.

```
                    Button(action: {
                        isSelecting = !isSelecting
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(selectedItem?.title ?? "Select Item")
                                .animation(.none)
                            Spacer()
                            if items.count > 1 {
                                Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                            }
                            
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.plain)
                    .animation(nil)
                    .disabled(items.count < 2)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isSelecting.toggle()
                    }
```

Comment: Using .buttonStyle(.plain) works better, but the effect is still there : https://imgur.com/a/xztJg45

Comment: Why didn't ```onTapGesture``` work for the items in the title? I would be trying to resolve that problem, then you can have it behave any way you like. This may help: [How to create a reusable button component in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76105625/20386264)

Comment: I tried this method, and it looks great, but it doesn't register the tap on the text, spacer, or icon, only some points between the outer space of the cell and the border of these 3 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom `ButtonStyle`. In `makeBody`, do not check `configuration.isPressed`. Always return an `accentColor`-colored label.

```
struct NoHighlightButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        // handle button role if necessary
        // if configuration.role == .destructive {
        //     configuration.label.foregroundColor(.red)
        // } else {
            configuration.label.foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        // }
    }
}
```